# How come the class "QuoteClientFactory" is not being understood as Defined in pycharm?

Tags: python, networking, pycharm, twisted

I am learning network programming with o'REilys Twisted network programming essential guide. (using pycharm IDE)

I have two issues the function maybeStopReactor() is not being recognized in pycharm and QuoteClientFactory isnot being seen as a defined class.

How can I go about finding a solution for this?

```
class QuoteClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, quote):
        self.quote = quote

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return QuoteProtocol(self)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print("connecton failed:"), reason.getErrorMessage()
        **maybeStopReactor()**

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print("connection lost"), reason.getErrorMessage()
        maybeStopReactor()

    def maybeStopReactor(self):
        global quote_counter
        quote_counter -=1
        if not quote_counter:
            reactor.stop()

    quotes = [
        "you snooze you lose",
        "The early bird gets the worm",
        "carpe diem"
    ]

    quote_counter = len(quotes)

    for quote in quotes:
        **reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 6942, QuoteClientFactory(quote))**
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: You cannot refer to a class before the end of its definition, as, well, it is not defined yet. Note that method bodies are not executed during the class definition, hence the class can be used inits own methods. Maybe you want to unindent everything starting from `quotes = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. It's a bit hard to see because the code spans a page break. What you want is:

```
class QuoteClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, quote):
        self.quote = quote

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return QuoteProtocol(self)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print("connecton failed:"), reason.getErrorMessage()
        maybeStopReactor()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print("connection lost"), reason.getErrorMessage()
        maybeStopReactor()

def maybeStopReactor():
    global quote_counter
    quote_counter -=1
    if not quote_counter:
        reactor.stop()

quotes = [
    "you snooze you lose",
    "The early bird gets the worm",
    "carpe diem"
]

quote_counter = len(quotes)

for quote in quotes:
    reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 6942, QuoteClientFactory(quote))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: in the twisted book the sample output is "Received quote: the early bird gets the worm" but what I am getting is just Received quote: do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? I am not sure what to be looking for?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.2 and i am using pycharm for the IDE. Should i try another IDE?

Comment: The line that's causing your problem is `print "Received quote:", data` in the `dataReceived` method of the `QuoteProtocol` class. Given that you're using Python 3, you must have refactored that line. Try `print(f"Received quote: {data}")`.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help! That seemed to fix the issue! How would I have figured that out with out your help? What could I have googled or documentation?